# .swiper-container & swiper-height problem of react-id-swiper in react js?

Tags: css, reactjs

I created a mousewheel control vertical slider now I wanted to make it mobile responsive to the height of the swiper-container I set 100% and it returns 5000px I think.

I set the height of swiper container static 618px it covers the window of the desktop but now I wanted to make it responsive it cause a problem 
it is stuck at 618px and returns white space at the bottom in the mobile screen.

```
  const params = {

      direction: 'vertical',

      slidesPerView: 1,
      spaceBetween: 0,
      mousewheel: true,
      pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true
      }
    }
    return (
      <Swiper {...params}>
        <div  id="homee">
          <Home/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Services/>
        </div>
        <div id="culture">

          <Culture/>
        </div>
        <div id="team">
          <Team/>
        </div>
        <div id="portfolio">

          <PortFolio/>
        </div>
        <div id="testimentials">

          <TestiMentals/>
        </div>
        <div id="updates">

          <Updates/>
        </div>
        <div id="currer">
          <JoinUs/>
        </div>
        <div id="contact">

        <Contact/>
        </div>
      </Swiper>
    )
  }//css.swiper-container{

  height:618px;
}
```